# Extract ROI from image by hand into Matrix Form

Tags: image-processing, image, regions

I have a 3D Image (each pixel contains information for various wavelengths).
I draw the image for one wavelength by using

```
Image[img[[All, All, 100]]] // ImageAdjust
```

whereas `img` is my Image.
Now I want to extract the Data in a certain ROI.
I do so by using the mask tool, but when I copy the mask, I get a fullsize image where the selected mask is white (I selected the following three squares):

[image]

How to extract the information from `img` (fully including the wavelength-dimension) for these regions? I.e. discarding the black areas completely. `ImageMultiply` doesnt help me, as this would just make those areas black again and not really discarding them.

Thanks

Comment: I guess that's "region of interest"? (I had at first thought "return on investment" but clearly that does not go with the question at hand.)

Comment: yes region of interest ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution:

```
mask = (* As seen above, copied from masking tool as a "Image *)
pos = Position[mask // ImageData, 1];
spectra = Extract[img, pos];
```